# Highchart LineChart MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src='http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>       
<script src='http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>    

</head>

<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456') or die('Error connecting to server');
mysql_select_db("aplikace", $con); 

$SQL1 =     "SELECT * FROM data";

$result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
$data1 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
   $data1[] = $row['cas'];
}

$result2 = mysql_query($SQL1);
$data2 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
   $data2[] = hexdec($row['pars_data']);
}


?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
             renderTo: 'container',
             type: 'line'
          },

        title:  {
                    text: 'Comming Data'
                },

        xAxis:  {
                    categories: ['<?php echo join($data1, "','") ?>'],
                },

        yAxis:  {
                    min:0,

                },

        legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 50,
                    y: 35,
                    floating: true,
                    shadow: true
                },

        plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                                    borderWidth: 0
                                }
                    },

        series: [   {
                        name: 'Data',
                        data: ['<?php echo join($data2, "','") ?>'],
                       // pointStart: 0
                        //pointInterval
                    },


                ]
    });
});
</script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Hi guys, I dont kwno where I have a mistake, could you help me please? On X-axis should be the datetime from column CAS-> it works but it doesnt display column PARS_DATA. Thanks for your help, thanks.

MySQL TABLE screen:

[image]

Chart which I see:

[image]

Comment: first why executing two times same query when you can do it only once? Second, did you print data2 array to see how it looks like?

Comment: for big numbers, hexdec uses scientific notation. Maybe that is messing values. try after hexdec using  number_format($hexdec_result, 0, '', '');

Comment: you are right i can do queries once, when i want to display `$data2` array chart disapper and I see nothing. Could you guide me please?

Comment: try using suggestion from my second comment.

Comment: where should i put `number_format($hexdec_result, 0, '', '');` in my code please i am confused

Comment: The best thing would be if you could dump that mysql table and then paste dump [here](http://pastebin.com/). After then put url you get here. Anyway, you could try in loop: $hexdec_result = hexdec($row['pars_data']);
   $data2[] = number_format($hexdec_result, 0, '', '');

Comment: [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35284336/graff.JPG) I used it in the loop and it displays on Y-axis this, but still no line

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pCFAmN53

Comment: i told you to paste sql dump (create and inserts for data table) so i can see how data looks like(pars_data too big to be shown by default in screenshot). I can see your HTML/Javascript code here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y9xZr0UC  I dont know if I understand you, my english is not good sorry

Comment: with this: data: [<?php echo join($data2,","); ?>] you can get results (without '') but they are again in scientific notation. Your numbers are huge and you can get them back to normal but with extra work to do.

Comment: xAxis should be Javascript timestamp, also please take look at http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing

Comment: yes i understad, i used smaller numbers and it works good thank you for your time:) I have one question, how can I add live data. My table is updating each 2 seconds and i want load new data to Chart, i can use meta tag to auto refresh but if its any posibility in Highchart?:)

Comment: go over [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update) example

Comment: actually you maybe need to combine first link with ajax loading of charts, like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your date time field to unix timestamp for process on it.
so strtotime function is good idea.

In your code, follow this :

```
 $result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
 if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $uts=strtotime($row['time']); //convert to Unix Timestamp
        $date=date("l, F j, Y H:i:s",$uts); //standard template for draw chart

        echo $date . "\t" . $row['new_cost']. "\n";  //only this template work 
    }
```

> $sql: your sql query text. 
>   $result: feedback.
>   $row['new_cost']: my field for cost.

for more details, follow [this](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/) link

good luck